# Fooman EmailAttachment = 'Payment Methods' is blank on the emailed PDF but not on the manually created PDF for Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, pdf, order-email

I have recently installed Fooman EmailAttachment module and my order email PDF doesn't display Payment Method information. Only payment method information is missing from Order PDF.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Did you find solution? Have the same problem.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/147936)